# How can I find a nearest object in grid coordinate

Tags: dictionary, geolocation, location, geometry, coordinates

I have the coordinates of the objects and the coordinates of the main object. The problem is as follows. How to find the nearest objects to the main object in order to build the nearest objects to the main object in the **form of a list**.

For example: there is a system of coordinates x, y. The main object is **located at: x = 20, y = 40**.

There are also 6 objects with addresses:

1. x = 22, y = 30
2. x = 26, y = 21
3. x = 29, y = 39
4. x = 42, y = 33
5. x = 48, y = 32
6. x = 23, y = 31

Based on the coordinates of the **main object - x = 20, y = 40**. We need to find the nearest coordinates from the six objects described above.

Thank you. If possible in the Java programming view, php, swift.

Comment: For small number of objects just sort them by (squared) distance. For larger sets use kd-tree

Comment: @MBo you can to explain in detail? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate squared distances to all objects as

```
SqDist[i] = (X[i] - Xobj)^2 + (Y[i] - Yobj)^2
```

Sort object list by `SqDist` key in ascending order (in Java make `Comparator` to compare `SqDist` fields)